# when MenuItem is clicked how to create a jTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jmenuitem

I would like to know how I can show the output from this piece of code...

```
File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Hugo Monteiro\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\FileImporter\\ImagensDB");   
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();   

for (int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length; i++) {   
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {   
        jTextArea1.append("File: " +listOfFiles[i].getName());  
    }   
}
```

I want to open this in a `JTextArea` after clicking the `JMenuItem` in a `JMenu`

```
private void jMenuItem6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    //code for Output  
    }
```

Could someone please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wont this do the trick?:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaApplication151 extends JFrame {

    private JMenuBar menu;
    private JMenu fileMenu;
    private JMenuItem showFilesMenuItem;
    private JTextArea ta;
    private JScrollPane areaPane;

    public JavaApplication151() {
        createAndShowUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JavaApplication151 test = new JavaApplication151();
                test.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        setTitle("Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        addComponentsToPane();
        addListeners();
        pack();
    }

    private void addComponentsToPane() {
        ta = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        areaPane = new JScrollPane(ta);
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        showFilesMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Show Files");
        menu = new JMenuBar();
        fileMenu.add(showFilesMenuItem);
        menu.add(fileMenu);
        getContentPane().add(areaPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    private void addListeners() {
        showFilesMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                ta.setText("");//clear textarea text
                listFiles();
            }

            private void listFiles() {
                File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Hugo Monteiro\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\FileImporter\\ImagensDB");
                File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                        ta.append("File: " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

you had the exact code just had to move your method to menu items actionPerformed() method unless i misunderstood the question?

Comment: +1 this must be it (@Robin nice and fast suggestion which doesn't assume anything about the location of the area). As an additional comment for the code I would also clear the area before appending the results, e.g. `ta.setText("")`, but maybe the OP doesn't need that. Anyway good sample.

Comment: @Boro added the ta.setText("") as suggested as Im sure it is necessary for the OP. +1. Thanks

Comment: sorry for my delay replaying to your help just lots of exams lately :\ i really appreciate, that did the trick thank u very much.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is probably to use a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) and pass your `JTextArea` to that `JOptionPane`. E.g. by calling the [`JOptionPane#showMessageDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) method